# Animation is lagging on Microsoft Edge and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, animation, microsoft-edge

I'm developing a simple type of animation with CSS and HTML.
It works perfect on Mozilla, Opera and Chrome but in Microsoft Edge and IE browsers it is lagging.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5nhu9ogg/12/) is an example of my code:

```css
.css-typing1 p {
  border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

.css-typing1 p:nth-child(1) {
  width: 18em;
  -webkit-animation: type 1.5s steps(40, end);
  animation: type 1.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing1 p:nth-child(2) {
  width: 18em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type2 1.5s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 1.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing1 p:nth-child(3) {
  width: 18em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type3 1.5s steps(40, end);
  animation: type3 1.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    /*border: none;*/
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    /*border: none;*/
  }
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: black
  }
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  }
  100% {
    border: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  }
  100% {
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="css-typing1">
  <p>
    Some text for row number 1
  </p>
  <p>
    Some text for row number 2
  </p>
  <p>
    Some text for row number 3
  </p>
</div>
```

As you can see from this example when the first row animation is finished, it shows the second row for a millisecond, then this second row disappears and starts typing as needed. The same for the third row.

How can I adjust my code so it won't show the second and the third row for this millisecond?

Comment: animation sucks in IE always :P - it always have performance issue also. I would not suggest any css animation.

Comment: @sinhavartika I have partially approved your edits, but you didn't make a code snippet, you just pasted hundreds of lines of code. Next time, make a snippet like I did :)

Comment: I think there's nothing to be done. If it was JS code, there would probably be room for improvement, but these are CSS keyframes, so it's just IE that's flawed.

Comment: see https://github.com/alexmacarthur/typeit.